# printing solution for .NET front end, MYSQL backend

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

i will need to print an "x" according to the coordinates given to me from one of the tables in my database. im probably gonig to use c# to connect to mysql.

i will probably have a winform that is 8.5 x 11 inches (The size of a regular sheet of paper) and i will populate the entire thing with labels of "x" and they will be invisible.

each individual table record will have the coordinates of those labels which should NOT be invisible

the form for every record will show and will print. the printing will be on top of a paper that is actually a physical application itself.

**the problem:**
how to fill out a physical application using data from a mysql database. (dont tell me that i should be printing the entire app from scratch, the reason this is not possible is because the form is actually TRIPLE paper width (white, yellow, and pink copy), so i cannot print the entire app from scratch, i have to print on top of it.

**the question:** how do i print "x" at specified regions? is my solution the best way to go or is there a smarter approach?

in case you have no idea what i am talking about, here are some related questions:
[ms-access: designing a report: printing text on specific x,y coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893070/ms-access-designing-a-report-printing-text-on-specific-x-y-coordinates)

[Conditional formatting in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906779/conditional-formatting-in-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While labels would offer you the ability to make an X show up I don't feel that having a bunch of hidden labels is the best way.

Does the "application" represent some kind of form?  Are you looking to "check-off" boxes using x's and then print this?

I may suggest using GDI+ (drawing) vs using labels.

Consider the following:
  Locate the coordinates for your boxes. Then use the drawstring method within an overridden onPaint event-handler for your form or for the panel which may represent your form's canvas.

This article talks about GDI+ and how to draw text as graphics.
http://www.functionx.com/vb/gdi+/objects/fonts.htm